# How can I write a C# method which will retrieve all directories in a directory tree using String[] and List<String[]>?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, arraylist

```
 public static List<string[]> SubSubFolders()
    {
       // int variable for while loop
        int i = 0;
        // String Array to hold top SubFol
        string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\");

        //List<String[]> to hold a list of arrays from dir
        List<string[]> subSub = new List<string[]>();

        string[] finalResult = new string[0];

        //Loop through all the folders in the dir.
        while (i < dir.Length)
        {
            string folder1 = dir(i);

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder1);
            if (!di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
            {   
                subSub.Add(Directory.GetDirectories(folder1));
            }
            i++;
        }

        return subSub;
    }
```

This is my code. My goal is to create a program that will allow me to go through all the directories exist below a given directory and to list them out in order that they appear. So for example the overall code would do this:

```
c:\documents
c:\documents\abtemp
c:\documents\abtemp\chuck
c:\documents\rubbish
c:\documents\state1
etc
```

I can print out the second level and about to move into deeper of the sub-directories. The problem I have is that my print-out does not show the top folders at all.

What I have done to resolve the issue: 
* Try to add the dir to subSub:  I get the error of cannot convert String to String[].
* Try to change subSub to string[] instead of list : I can't add sub directories to the array.
* Try to change dir to List instead of string[]: 
    * Directory.GetDirectories gives an error of Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

So my questions: How do I add either my dir to subSub or vice versa to complete the list? Is there a cleaner way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, so I'm not sure exactly what the problem you want help with it, but I think I see what you are trying to achieve - to run down through the folder tree and list all the folders?

If so, the best way to do this is with a recursive function - make the function call itself until it gets to the bottom of the tree, adding to a list as it goes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        SubSubFolders(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office", list);

        Console.WriteLine(list.Aggregate((s1,s2)=>s1+Environment.NewLine+s2));
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static void SubSubFolders(string basePath, List<string> folders)
    {
        //if (folders.Count > 500) return;
        string[] dirs = new string[] { };
        try
        {
            dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            // Handle access failures - there will be folders you can't enumerate unless running as admin
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
        {
            folders.Add(dirs[i]);
            SubSubFolders(dirs[i], folders);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will take a long time if you try to enumerate all directories on the average computer - say from c:\.  For that you would need some serious optimisation and probably to move to a lower level language if you want really good performance.

Note also that you can't easily add to an array - it's size is set at the time it is created.